# Should Redux async thunk actions always return promises if they contain promises

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, promise

I have an async thunk action that performs a number of things... but I don't really need to "wait" on the thunk action itself.  Instead, state will eventually be changed, triggering component props to change, triggering component lifecycle methods to be called.

Thus, is it okay to have async thunk actions return void if I don't actually care about waiting upon them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care about waiting, there is nothing that requires you to return a promise from your thunk. In general with async thunks, I would return a promise, since it's oftentimes just a matter of adding a return statement and I often do chain off of the promise to handle loading state in the components, but again, no requirement. In your specific situation, where it sounds like you're just triggering a bunch of different things, just returning void sounds reasonable to me. You can always return a Promise.all around the various requests at a later date if you do want to chain off of it down the line.